# How can I scrape a website with login page using Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to login to a website, however I couldn't and also I'm new to Dart.
I tried run this code:

```
var url = "https://example.com/login";
  http.post(url, body: {"login": "xxxxx", "password": "xxxx"})
      .then((response) {
    print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
    print("Response body: ${response.body}");
```

After that I am getting post request:

```
Response status: 302
Response body: //empty
```

Answer (score 1):

A 302 means a redirect – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Look at the `location` header in the response and do another request!

Comment: But, how? I couldn't save cookie to redirect another website like JSOUP in Java.